# Where is my Minecraft folder on Windows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't have a minecraft folder. I've looked through forums and videos, followed all the steps. I just don't have one. I have windows 7, and I have "view hidden files" turned on. I have look in the roaming folder of my app data folder, with hidden files turned on. I want to find my folder so I can install a mod, could someone please tell me why my folder isn't showing up?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you've run Minecraft on your machine, then you *do* have a .minecraft folder.  It can be a bit tricky to find.  Here's an easy way to get to it:

1. Launch Minecraft.
2. Select "Options"
3. Select "Resource Packs..."
4. Select "Open resource pack folder"
5. Go up one level

Answer (score 27):

To get to the .minecraft folder, you can always just open Run from the start menu and type `%appdata%\.minecraft\`, then click Run. It'll open your minecraft folder.

Answer (score 10):

If you're on windows, go to to your start menu and search `%appdata%`. This will bring your to a collection of folders. One of these folders is labeled `.minecraft`. Hope this helps! If your on Mac, go to finder, open up the `library` folder, inside of the library folder, open up the `Application support` file, inside should be your `.minecraft` file. Here are the relevant file paths

## Windows

```
%appdata%\.minecraft
```

## Mac OSX

```
~/Library/Application Support/minecraft
```