# Where do I find screenshots taken in Minecraft on Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Windows 10. I can't seem to find any of my screenshots.

I've looked over on YouTube and Safari but I can't find any tutorials on how to open screenshots on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the game directory for some kind of screenshots folder?

Comment: Relevant: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28717/where-is-my-minecraft-folder-on-windows

Comment: Er... Do you need help opening, navigating to the files, or both? Because you're being ambiguous with your question..

Comment: Might appear too broad for some, but the poster is asking specific to Windows 10, where screenshots and videos are localised.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is an operating system question.

Comment: This isn't OS specific from a Minecraft perspective due to its internal screenshot.  The problem is that it is storing it in a ".minecraft" folder which on most OSs is a "hidden" folder.  I believe that this is a duplicate of the Relevant question MrLemon shared and the answer is this:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/28720/68757

Comment: While the title may be a little misleading, the question is less "how do I open an image" and more "where does minecraft store images under Windows 10", and is not off-topic. Additionally, I do not believe this is a duplicate of how to find the .minecraft folder. While the answer to this might effectively be a subfolder of .minecraft conveniently called screenshots, that does not necessarily answer where minecraft stores screenshots.

Comment: @TrentHawkins true. IIRC screenshots are affected by the profiles Game Directory setting, so they might be somewhere else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

If your using the game center feature of Windows 10, you take screenshots by pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>. *(Windows Key + Alt + Print Screen)*

You will find the screenshots in your Videos folder, in a sub-folder named Captures. This is the same place game recordings will be placed, as well.

```
User > Videos > Captures
       or:
C:\Users\[Your username]\Videos\Captures
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question either.  Minecraft has a internal screen shot feature which he is likely using.

Comment: I make the presumption that OP has basic computer capablity, and OP would already be capable pf searching the word "screenshot", which would direct you to minecrafts in-house captured shots. The other is not really a presumption. OP states they have already searched all over the internet, inhouse screenshots for windows 10 comes up if you google "minecraft screenshot windows 10".

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes the Java version of the game is used, not the new Windows 10 version (I have not tried that yet).

If you just created a screenshot, the name of the created file will be shown in the chat stream. Simply click that name to open the screenshot in your default image viewer.

Otherwise, start the MineCraft launcher and activate the 'Edit Profile' button for your current profile. On the newly opened Profile Editor window, activate the 'Open Game Dir' button to open the game directory.
A subdirectory of that called 'screenshots' contains your screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new file explorer Window, and in the address bar, input `%AppData%\Roaming%\.minecraft\screenshots` and press enter. You can also find it from entering the aforementioned address in your start menu. This folder is a subdirectory of your users folder, and will be placed in `C:\Your_Username\AppData`. If you want to make this folder easier to find, you can either display hidden files and folders by doing the following.

Display hidden files and folders:

- 1. Right-click the Windows Logo button and choose Explore.
- 2. Click Organize and choose Folder and Search Options.
- 3. Click the View tab, select Show hidden files and folders andthen clear the checkbox for Hide protected system operating files.
- 4. Click Yes on the warning and then click OK.

You can also make a shortcut to the .minecraft folder and place it somewhere convenient (like your desktop). Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

When you're on Minecraft and take a screenshot it doesn't actually save it to your photos folder. What you have to do is after you take a screenshot on Minecraft, open your chat and click on the screenshot URL thingy. It'll open another window and what you need to do is press the save icon at the top right of your screen and then go to your photos and you'll hopefully find them. This happened to me and it took me ages to figure it out haha. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link that it shows you once you have taken the screenshot. (I just did this to test the theory listed above) It will bring it up in your photos app. It is in your appdata folder on the C drive. I am having a hard time finding it without clicking on the link even with the file name and everything.

Answer (score 0):

For people that are unaware of the answer go into where Cortana is and type %appdata% and then click  .Minecraft then screenshots
(Windows 10 only)

Answer (score -6):

You need to push <kbd>f2</kbd>. If that doesn't work then check your keyboard settings and change <kbd>f2</kbd> to something else.

Comment: Signatures aren't really needed here, first of all. And second, you haven't specified how to *open* one.

Comment: Its worth noting that some keyboards have the quick keys on the function line as the main buttons. So sometimes you will have to press FN + F2 for the same effect.

Comment: Er... OP's asking how to open one **not** how to make one...