# Cannot find .minecraft folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I see everyone using mods in Minecraft go into their File Explorer, type in `%appdata%` in the top search bar, and then in that folder they have a Minecraft folder in which there should be a mod file (you can make your own mod folder). The thing is that I can't find the Minecraft folder in `%appdata%`.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Are your files and folders set to hidden? To check, go to Start, type "file explorer options", hit enter, go to the 'View' tab, and, under 'Hidden Files and Folders', select 'Show hidden files, folders, and drives'. Now navigate to %appdata% again and see if the .minecraft folder shows up.

Comment: This isn't how minecraft modding works, at least not nowadays. As you're on 1.14, try using [fabric](https://fabricmc.net/) with something like multimc.

Comment: @Ave The described procedure is for Forge. And yes, Forge still exists and is used.

Comment: ...are you sure you have launched a copy of minecraft before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is my Minecraft folder on Windows?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28717/where-is-my-minecraft-folder-on-windows)

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Timmy Jim's comment.

Comment: Voting to close this question as "Needs details or clarity" as OP didn't respond to Joachim's comment above asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find it is to open your resource packs, then from there click the option to "Open Resource Pack Folder". This will take you to the directory where everything should be stored.

The resource pack folder sits under the .minecraft folder, so from there you'll be able to navigate through and find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Go in here:

```
C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft
```

Make sure you turned on hidden items.

For turn on hidden items, go in your file explorer and click the "View" in top of the screen and then turn on "Hidden items".

Comment: Could you clarify? How do you "turn on hidden files"? Don't assume that the OP will be able to connect the dots themselves. Assume that they don't know anything, because answers are for the whole community, not just the OP, and there will probably be some people coming across this who don't know anything.

Comment: The only hidden folder is the AppData folder, though. They can't find `.minecraft`, which isn't hidden.