# .minecraft is not in my roaming file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

I am trying to get the create mod for minecraft and I cannot find my .minecraft folder. I watched some tutorials but nothing worked I have tried typing in %APPDATA%.minecraft into quick access and it doesn't come up with anything. How else can I find it or is it just not there and if so how can i get it?

Here is a  screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Try `%APPDATA%\.minecraft` (you need the slash).

Comment: I tried all the solutions given for the other question but none of them worked.

Comment: The folder is likely hidden. Type 'folder options' in the Start menu, open the Options that show up, and on the second tab (I believe) you can find an option to show all files and folders.

Comment: @Joachim I have checked, it is not hidden.

Comment: The duplicate suggested should work. [Try this answer in the duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/28718/258509). If you messed with the installation settings this should tell you where the game directory is located.

Comment: From the minecraft starting screen where is options?

Answer (score 0):

Just search only the word "%APPDATA%" and there you will find a folder named ".minecraft" : )

Comment: It doesn't work for me